# When using Ubuntu Gnome the screen will turn black and it'll show only two command lines

Tags: gnome

Sometimes, if I try to close a program (Firefox, LibreOffice, Spotify, etc.) it will close and also the screen will turn black showin only two command lines. Is this some kind of bug? Is there anything I can do to solve this without reinstalling?

Comment: how exactly are you closing those programmes, by mouse or keyboard? What do the lines say?

Comment: Alt+F4; the bottom line reads my user name.

Comment: Boot to the GRUB menu. Choose Advanced Options. Choose Recovery mode. Choose ROOT access. Type `fsck -f /` and run that command until there are no errors. Then type `reboot`. Let me know if that fixes your problem. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> in Linux systems promps that console it isn't a bug, it's completely normal.

Comment: Xorg normally prevents that, you have to press Ctrl-Alt-F4 to switch to the virtual terminal 4.

Comment: Sorry I will correct it

Answer (score 1):

You're switching to another virtual terminal. The pretty graphics run on one of many (theoretically up to 12) virtual terminals. The key combination to change from one virtual terminal to the other is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>. This means that sometimes when you close application with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, the Ctrl key somehow also gets pressed. When that happens, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or another F* key, if <kbd>f7</kbd> doesn't work — trial and error so to speak…) to return to the desktop.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still trying to find my way through Ubuntu, it's quite a challenge.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this command when this is happens:

1. Open the Terminal or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Run this command `xkill` it will show you a (x) cursor.
3. Select the app That you want to close.